# How to return a failure if a table is empty

Tags: sql-server-2005, ssis, dts

Using SQL Server 2005, but still using DTS.  I need to add a step to check if a table is empty, and somehow fail the step if it is.  It's easy checking if the table is empty:

```
Select count(*) from source_table
```

But returning 0 is a success, too.  If it is 0, I want a failure (so that I can fork to a different option, email us, skip some steps).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I didn't use DTS.  It was resolved in SSIS, although, looking back, I could have probably done something similar in DTS.

Step 1: A data flow task that selects count and saves that count to a variable.  The select count took a bit of work:

```
select cast(count(*) as integer) as Row_Count from MyTable
```

and then the output of the data flow task was a script component that was a destination and had an input column as that ROW_COUNT, and my ReadWriteVariables as TableCount (the variable that was used as input in step 2)

Step 2: A script task that evaluates that count and fails if the count was 0, succeeds otherwise.  Forking from this is a success route and a failure route.

Comment: If you're going to give a downvote, especially on such an old question, it would be nice to give a comment as to why.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (select count(*) from [Table]) = 0 print 'Empty'
```

Comment: That isn't raising an error, and I don't think printing is normally what is needed in DTS or SSIS processing.

Comment: @thursdaysgeek : I thought you are capable of changing print with raiserror(), sorry :)

Answer (score 1):

what about returning -1 ?

```
Select 
   case when count(*)>=0 then count(*) else -1 end 
from 
   source_table
```

If you really want to raise an error, you can use [RAISERROR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177497.aspx) to do just that :

```
Declare @RowCount as bigint
set @RowCount=count(*) from source_table
if RowCount =0
RAISERROR ('error message', 50000, 1)  with log
```

Comment: How do you use RAISEERROR in a DTS Execute SQL Task?

Comment: A potentially better way to check for an empty table:

if not exists (select top 1 0 from source_table)
  raiserror(...)

Answer (score 0):

You can divide by count result:

```
Select 1/count(*) from source_table
```

Comment: I'm a couple of jobs past that issue, so have no way of testing, but this does seem like it could be a good solution.