# How to count empty tables in database?

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Is there any way to count tables with no rows in my database with using `T-SQL` statement?

Comment: refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5630689/select-all-empty-tables-in-sql-server/50603510#50603510

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There you go... using a derived table.

```
SELECT * FROM
(
 SELECT 
  [TableName] = so.name, 
  [RowCount] = MAX(si.rows) 
 FROM 
  sysobjects so, 
  sysindexes si 
 WHERE 
  so.xtype = 'U' 
  AND 
  si.id = OBJECT_ID(so.name) 
 GROUP BY 
  so.name 
) sub
WHERE sub.[RowCount] = 0
```

Answer (score 4):

I use the following:

```
SELECT t.NAME AS TableName, sum(p.rows) as RowCounts
    FROM sys.tables t
INNER JOIN sys.indexes i
    ON t.OBJECT_ID = i.object_id
INNER JOIN sys.partitions p
    ON i.object_id = p.OBJECT_ID AND i.index_id = p.index_id
WHERE
    i.name IS NULL AND i.index_id <= 1
GROUP BY 
    t.NAME, i.object_id, i.index_id, i.name 
HAVING SUM(p.rows) = 0
```

Comment: I really like this approach because you just the tables and row counts.  If you need table size or views, procs, etc then sys.objects helps.

Answer (score 1):

from **khtan** @ [SQL Server Forums](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1368632/how-to-return-a-failure-if-a-table-is-empty), this is used to *drop* all empty tables, maybe you could adapt it to output a count?

```
declare @name varchar(128), @sql nvarchar(2000), @i int
select  @name = ''
while   @name < (select max(name) from sysobjects where xtype = 'U')
begin
    select @name = min(name) from sysobjects where xtype = 'U' and name > @name
    select @sql = 'select @i = count(*) from [' + @name + ']'
    exec sp_executesql @sql, N'@i int out', @i out
    if @i = 0
    begin
        select @sql = 'drop table [' + @name + ']'
        print @sql
            -- unmask next to drop the table
        -- exec (@sql)
    end
end
```

I don't have SQLServer here but I could take a stab at it if you like.

Comment: @Rubens Farias, I don't understand, `-- exec (@sql)` is already commented out?