# Select all empty tables in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

How to get the list of the tables in my `sql-server` database that do not have any records in them?

Comment: Here, is a Similar Discussion. Refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2132701/t-sql-how-to-count-empty-tables-in-database ) Hope its helpful to you.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

On SQL Server 2005 and up, you can use something like this:

```
;WITH TableRows AS
(
   SELECT 
      SUM(row_count) AS [RowCount], 
      OBJECT_NAME(OBJECT_ID) AS TableName
   FROM 
      sys.dm_db_partition_stats
   WHERE 
      index_id = 0 OR index_id = 1
   GROUP BY 
      OBJECT_ID
)
SELECT *
FROM TableRows
WHERE [RowCount] = 0
```

The inner select in the CTE (Common Table Expression) calculates the number of rows for each table and groups them by table (`OBJECT_ID`), and the outer SELECT from the CTE then grabs only those rows (tables) which have a total number of rows equal to zero.

**UPDATE:** if you want to check for non-Microsoft / system tables, you need to extend the query like this (joining the `sys.tables` catalog view):

```
;WITH TableRows AS
(
   SELECT 
       SUM(ps.row_count) AS [RowCount], 
       t.Name AS TableName
   FROM 
       sys.dm_db_partition_stats ps
   INNER JOIN
       sys.tables t ON t.object_id = ps.object_id
   WHERE 
       (ps.index_id = 0 OR ps.index_id = 1)
       AND t.is_ms_shipped = 0
   GROUP BY 
       t.Name
)
SELECT *
FROM TableRows
WHERE [RowCount] = 0
```

Comment: The only one I have found that works on SQL Azure as well.  Thanks!

Comment: When I ran this query against SQL Azure it got me many system tables. I don't want to filter the result for user tables. Maybe the query could be tweaked to remove the system tables?

Comment: @mortb: posted an updated/adapted version, that excludes all Microsoft-shipped (system) tables from the results

Answer (score 26):

To get the list of empty tables, we can use the below tsql –

```
EXEC sp_MSforeachtable 'IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM ?) PRINT ''?'' '
```

And, to get a list of tables having at least one row of data, we can use the below tsql –

```
EXEC sp_MSforeachtable 'IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM ?) PRINT ''?'' '
```

Note: List of table included only 'User Table' i.e. Not included 'System Table'.

Answer (score 6):

```
select a.rows as Rowcnt,
   b.name as Tbl_Name 
from sys.partitions a
join sys.tables b
   on a.object_id=b.object_id
where b.type='u' 
   and a.rows = 0
```

Comment: select distinct b.name as tableName,a.rows as rowsCount
from sys.partitions a 
join sys.tables b
   on a.object_id=b.object_id
where b.type='u' and a.rows =0 order by a.rows

Comment: or, group and sum results

Answer (score 2):

```
  SELECT name AS [TableList] FROM SYS.DM_DB_PARTITION_STATS s 
  INNER JOIN sys.tables t ON t.[object_id] = s.[object_id]
  WHERE row_count = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

We can simply classify Tables into two types.

1. Clustered Table ( Tables having a Clustered Index )
2. Heap Tables (
       Tables not having a Clustered Index )

In SQL Server, all tables are divided into `partitions`. There will be at least one partition for each table .

In [`sys.partitions`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50602998/6281993), there exists one row for each `partition` of all tables.

The entries in `sys.partitions` contains a column for **number of rows** in that partition of the corresponding table.

Since all tables in SQL Server contain aleast one partition, we can get the information about number of rows in a table from `sys.partitions`.

```
SELECT
        OBJECT_NAME(T.OBJECT_ID) AS TABLE_NAME,
        SUM(P.ROWS)  AS TOTAL_ROWS
FROM
        SYS.TABLES T
INNER JOIN 
        SYS.PARTITIONS P 
        ON T.OBJECT_ID = P.OBJECT_ID
WHERE 
        P.INDEX_ID IN (0,1)
GROUP BY 
        T.OBJECT_ID
HAVING 
        SUM(P.ROWS) = 0
```

While taking sum of rows in different partitions, we are considering `index_id` **(0,1)**

- `index_id = 0 for Heap`
- `index_id = 1 for Clustered index`
- `index_id > 1 are for nonclustered index.`

A table can have either one clustered index or none.

But a table can have multiple nonclustered indexes.
So we cannot use `index_id`s of nonclustered indexes while summing rows.

- Heap Tables will be having `index_id = 0`
- Clustered Tables will be having `index_id = 1`

Answer (score 0):

1. We can find all empty tables by using below code.

```sql
select schema_name(tab.schema_id) + '.' + tab.name as [TableList] 
from sys.tables tab 
inner join sys.partitions part 
on tab.object_id = part.object_id 
where part.index_id IN (1, 0) 
group by schema_name(tab.schema_id) + '.' + tab.name 
having sum(part.rows) = 0 
order by [TableList]
```