# Find All Empty Tables Named MAP_ALERT In All Databases On Server

Tags: sql-server

We perform studies at my job, and each study has its own database. All the study databases are on the same server, and eaxch has a table named MAP_ALERT.

I need to find all MAP_ALERT tables that contain no data, for all the study databases. I found this page that tells how to find empty tables in one database: [Select all empty tables in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5630689/select-all-empty-tables-in-sql-server) - how can I adapt this to find ALL empty tables named MAP_ALERT in ALL database on a given server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use dynamic sql here to help you out. This is querying the system tables for each database. This will even properly handle databases that don't have that table.

```
declare @SQL nvarchar(MAX)
set @SQL = '';

create table #Results
(
    DBName sysname
)

select @SQL = @SQL + 'if exists(select * from ' + name + '.sys.tables where name = ''MAP_ALERT'') insert #results (DBNAME) select ''' + name + ''' from ' + name + '.dbo.MAP_ALERT having count(*) > 0;'
from sys.databases

--select @SQL
--uncomment the following when you have evaluated the dynamic sql and understand what query is going to run on your system
exec sp_executesql @SQL

select * from #Results
```

Comment: This is helpful, but it seems to only be querying one database. How can I get it to cycle through all of them?

Comment: It is querying all the databases on a single instance. That is why the select statement is pulling from sys.databases. It doesn't have to cycle or loop. Try it and you will see.

Comment: I did try it, it only pulled one database name and that one doesn't even have the MAP_ALERT table. Not sure if SQL Server version matters but this is an old legacy application using 2005.

Comment: Ummm are you sure you ran the code I posted? I added that table to 2 databases, one with rows and another without and it works perfectly. What you describe doesn't make sense with the code posted.

Comment: Ohh....I know what you did. You ran this and didn't read or understand the code. If you had you would notice the commented out exec sp_executesql @SQL line and the comment that states you should uncomment it.

Comment: I *did* uncomment that line. First I got the error, "Cannot assign a default value to a local variable." I had to take out the "= ''". Then I ran it again and "select @sql" returned NULL. Then I ran it again and "select @sql" returned a single line with a single database name populated, and the #results temp table was empty, even though I know results should have come back..

Comment: That is because that line is to show you the contents of the dynamic sql before you run it. I will edit this so it will work in sql 2005.

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned the version.  This is working now, thanks! +1 and marked as answer.

Comment: Not a problem at all. Do you understand what this code does?

Comment: Yes I do. I'm not a noob, I just haven't had occasion to cycle through all the databases on a server before and wasn't sure how to do it.

Comment: No need to take offense. I didn't say you were a noob. I merely asked if you understand it.

Comment: Which came across as condescending. I had already asked a question about something I didn't know how to do - if I didn't understand the answer I would have asked for clarification. Thanks for your help in any case.