# Counting no of empty tables in a database sql server

Tags: sql-server

I am new to sql server can anybody help me in the above code. i have written it like this to calculate the empty tables in a database

```
declare @tablenm nvarchar(100) 
declare @sqlquery nvarchar 
declare c1 cursor for select table_name from information_schema.tables where table_type='base table' 
open c1 
fetch next from c1 into @tablenm 
while @@fetch_status=0 
Begin 
set @sqlquery='Select count(*) from '+@tablenm
```

//How to execute the above query now and store the value in a variable and check if its zero if its zero then print the table name. i am trying to write this in sql server please help

Comment: You are missing "end" for the while clause. typo?

Comment: Thanks that i know i havent written the entire query just need a help how to execute that dynamic query and store that value in a variable so that i can check if that value is zero i will print the table name.

Comment: There are several issues here. Missing END, you seem to be using dynamic sql but you never execute it, you don't fetch again inside your cursor, you defined @sqlquery as nvarchar but no size, it will default to 30. But the biggest issue is using a cursor for this. sys.dm_db_partition_stats would be a much better approach.

Comment: In case of use here are a few times people have asked similar questions: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/189388/how-to-find-number-of-empty-tables-in-any-schema and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2132701/how-to-count-empty-tables-in-database

Answer (score 2):

Please try the code below:

```
;WITH cte AS
(
   SELECT 
      SUM(row_count) AS [RowCount], 
      OBJECT_NAME(OBJECT_ID) AS TableName
   FROM 
      sys.dm_db_partition_stats
   WHERE 
      index_id = 0 OR index_id = 1
   GROUP BY 
      OBJECT_ID
)
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE [RowCount] = 0
```

EDIT: Another alternative is on the below.

```
EXEC sp_MSforeachtable 'IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM ?) PRINT ''?'' '
```

Comment: i dont have permission for this action so can you please let me know how to store the value executing the query which i wrote and check if its value is zero or not

Comment: @Aamir can you try the editted part? Make sure you are using the correct DB.

Comment: Hi Erya its working can you just help me in last one query i am stuck in i want to find all the empty columns in of a tables in my database.My database name is drnk_mscrm